# save word 2010 document as pdf with bookmarks

Tags: microsoft-word, pdf, bookmarks

I am saving word-document (master- and subdocuments in MS Word 2010 on Windows 7) as a pdf with the bookmark option (create bookmarks using headings).
Now the funny thing:
It works for all subdocuments but one subdocument (after ca. 80 pages of 104) - and it is not the last subdoc - and I don't see any differences compared to the other subdocuments.

Any idea what I could check, or what prevents creating bookmarks?

Answer (score 1):

1. Click the Microsoft Office Button , point to the arrow next to Save As, and then click PDF.
2. In the Save as type list, click PDF Document.
3. In the Publish as PDF  dialog box, click Options to display the following item.

Under Include non-printing information:

- **Create bookmarks using**

Check this check box to create bookmarks in the document based on your selection. If the document contains headings, Headings is available. If the document contains bookmarks, Word bookmarks is available.